# if-else statement inside for loop for R

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I've read through some of the if-else if question for for loop, but I cannot seem to solve what the problem is for my script.

```
type = numeric(length(r))

for (i in 1:10) {
    if ( ((s_mov[i] < s_rot[i]) & (e_rot[i] < e_mov[i])) | ((s_rot[i] < s_mov[i]) & (s_mov[i] < e_rot[i])) == TRUE) {
        type[i]=1
    } 
    else if ( ((s_doc[i] < s_rot[i]) & (e_rot[i] < e_doc[i]) == TRUE) {
        type[i]=2
    }
    else if ( ((s_rot[i] < e_mov[i]) & (s_doc[i] < e_rot[i])) | ((s_rot[i] < s_mov[i]) & (s_doc[i] < e_rot[i])) == TRUE) {
        type[i]=3
    }
}
```

or I've tried this way as well

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    if ( ((s_mov[i] < s_rot[i]) & (e_rot[i] < e_mov[i])) | ((s_rot[i] < s_mov[i]) & (s_mov[i] < e_rot[i])) == TRUE) {
        type[i]=1
    } 
    else if ( ((s_doc[i] < s_rot[i]) & (e_rot[i] < e_doc[i]) == TRUE) {
        type <- replace(type, type[i],2
    }
    else if ( ((s_rot[i] < e_mov[i]) & (s_doc[i] < e_rot[i])) | ((s_rot[i] < s_mov[i]) & (s_doc[i] < e_rot[i])) == TRUE) {
        type <- replace(type, type[i],3
    }
}
```

but I'm constantly getting

```
Error: unexpected '{' in:
```

What's wrong?

I'm not sure but I think depending on the data, when all 1:10 satisfy first if statement, it writes 1 for all 10 elements, and rather than stooping, it continues and cause error.

Comment: An unexpected `{` means you have a simple syntax error. You just need to look harder for it. Probably an unclosed paren.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing several closing brackets in different places.  I highly recommend using a good IDE, such as RStudio, which has a side-benefit of highlighting the matching brackets.

Both the `type <- replace...` statements need a closing `)`.
Just by eyeballing, it looks like the first `else if` is missing a closing `)` as well:

```
else if ( ((s_doc[i] < s_rot[i]) & (e_rot[i] < e_doc[i]) == TRUE) {
```

you have 4 opening and only 3 closing brackets in there.

I haven't checked the other statements, but you should.

Comment: You miscounted the brackets, they're fine.

Comment: Are you sure? I just counted again and definitely counted 4 opening and 3 closing

Comment: Do you mean brackets '[' and ']' or parentheses '(' and ')'?  Brackets are fine, parens are lacking.

Answer (score -1):

In the first example, your first `else if` has an extra `(`.

In the second example, your first `else if` has an extra `(`, and your `replace` functions have no `)`.